# How to modify json_encode function file in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, mysqli

code:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var events = <?php echo $results; ?>;
        $("#calen").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var result = [true, '', null];
                var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
                    return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
                });

                if (matching.length) {
                    result = [true, 'highlight', null];
                }
                return result;
            },
            onSelect: function(dateText) {
                var date,
                    selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
                    i = 0,
                    event = null;

                while (i < events.length && !event) {
                    date = events[i].Date;

                    if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
                        event = events[i];
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (event) {
                    alert(event.Title);
                }
            }
        });
      });
</script>

<?php
    $sqls = mysqli_query($con,"select pack_program, pack_duration, start_date, end_date from package_detail where pack_name = '".$row['pack_name']."'");
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($sqls))
    {
        $data[] = array(
                            'Title' => $fetch['pack_program'],
                            'Duration' => $fetch['pack_duration'],
                            'Date' => "new Date(".$fetch['start_date'].")"
                        );
    }
    $results = str_replace('</', '<\/', json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
?>
```

Expected Output:

```
var events = [{Title:"Tour Program : Delhi / Chandigargh Arrival - Shimla ( 02 Nights ) – Manali ( 03 nights ) – Chandigarh ( 01 night ) Delhi / Chandigargh Departure Total : 06 Nights & 07 Days Tour",Duration:"7 days 6 Nights",Date:new Date("08/28/2018")}];
```

Unexpected Output:

```
var events = [{"Title":"Tour Program : Delhi / Chandigargh Arrival - Shimla ( 02 Nights ) – Manali ( 03 nights ) – Chandigarh ( 01 night ) Delhi / Chandigargh Departure Total : 06 Nights & 07 Days Tour","Duration":"7 days 6 Nights","Date":"new Date(08/28/2018)"}];
```

In the following code I have create a event calendar using jQuery datepicker which working fine for `expected output` as I mention above. But it does't work for `unexpected output` mention above. So, How can I modify in `$data[]` file which gives `expected output` to me. How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Your "expected output" is invalid json.

Comment: okk. But can you tell me that how can I remove double quote from `"new Date(08/28/2018)"` and get `new Date("08/28/2018")` @simon

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `JSON.parse()`

```
var events = <?php echo $results; ?>;
var obj = JSON.parse(events);
```

To learn more -> [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: what happen if I use JSON.parse(events) can you tell me. @menaka

Comment: what are you getting from php is a json string, from JSON.parse it will convert to a object

Comment: actually I want to replace double quotes from date and want output like `new Date("08/28/2018")`. Do you have any idea about this ? @menaka

Comment: @omkara the goal you're achieving is not as friendly as expected. As menaka suggests, parsing the JSON string into JSON object is the most suitable way for further processing.

Comment: do you want to `new Date("08/28/2018")` as  a string or date object ?

Comment: @menaka, he want it works with `datepicker`, so I think it should be and object, as expect result will be. But after `JSON.parse`, this value is still string, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah its gonna be a string. @omkara, Why dont you just pass a date string and convert it to a date object on the javascript. that would be a easy solution

Answer (score 0):

As your expect output, `new Date("08/28/2018")` will become a Date object, but in unexpect output, it is a string.

Let you try to change your code as:

```
$data[] = array(
                        'Title' => $fetch['pack_program'],
                        'Duration' => $fetch['pack_duration'],
                        'Date' => date('Y-m-d', $fetch['start_date'])
                    );
```

The out put will be:

```
var events = [{"Title":"Tour Program : Delhi / Chandigargh Arrival - Shimla ( 02 Nights ) – Manali ( 03 nights ) – Chandigarh ( 01 night ) Delhi / Chandigargh Departure Total : 06 Nights & 07 Days Tour","Duration":"7 days 6 Nights","Date":"2018-08-28"}];
```

and it will work with `datepicker`

Comment: But I don't want `"Date":"2018-08-28"` I want only `new Date("08/28/2018")`  @blue qn

Comment: `'"new Date(08/28/2018)"'.replace(/"new Date\(([^\)]+)\)"/, 'new Date("$1")')` will have output `new Date("08/28/2018")`. But I dont think it can work with `datepicker`

Comment: How can I use it @blue qn